# CRM 2011 Plugin - Get the Statecode on create of a task

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a plugin registered on Post of Task creation, I am trying to check the RegardingObject, ActualMinutes field and State Code of the task, however, the StateCode always seems to return 0 when creating a new task (even if you choose mark complete).

Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

```
OptionSetValue statecode = (OptionSetValue)entity["statecode"];
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("regardingobjectid") && entity.Attributes.Contains("actualdurationminutes") && statecode.Value == 1)
                { //DO STUFF }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that when using "*Mark as complete*", CRM saves the Task first and then uses a separate [SetStateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx) to mark it as complete. Which means you'll never be able to get other StateCode then 0 at that point in time in your post-create event.

I think you'll have to hook the plugin onto the **update event** on Task and check if that cracks it for you.

Comment: I recommend registering a Post plug-in on the SetState message. It will reduce the number of times the plug-in fires but should still allow you to get any instance where the activity is completed.